# How do I create an Encoder of type List[Row] for creating a Dataset[ List[Row] ] in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Basically, I am performing 'groupbyKey' followed by 'mapGroups' transformation on spark dataframe. 'mapGroups' will produce Dataset[U], which requires an Encoder of type 'U'. I am converting each group of value to List[Row] type, for that I have to pass an Encoder. I am able to create Encoder of type 'Row' by its schema, but don't know how to create Encoder for 'List[Row]' datatype.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders._
val groupedDataset = df.repartition($"_id")
                        .groupByKey(row => row.getAs[Long]("_id"))
                        .mapGroups((key,value) => value.toList)( ??? Here Encoder of List[Row] is Required ???)`
```

Comment: Which library is this? Is it a Spark-specific encoder or are we talking about something generic, such as JSON encoding?

Comment: Yes, It is related to spark dataset's encoder. I added a code snippet.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate `groupBy` + `agg(collect_list)`  or am I missing something?

Comment: My use case is as follow: I have a dataframe and I want to combine set of rows grouped by key and store it into any type of collection (It can be anything like List, Array or even Dataframe or Dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Seq with  import spark.implicits._
But you don't need to implement it if this is u use case u can use

`df.groupBy("_id").agg(collect_list("the column you want to collect of values"))`

Comment: My use case is as follow: I have a dataframe and I want to combine set of rows grouped by key and store it into any type of collection (It can be anything like List, Array or even Dataframe or Dataset). How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried the pseudo code i wrote it should do just that?

Comment: Yes, It is right. But what if I have to collect all columns in agg? Should I manually write all column name as collect_list or Is there a better way?

Comment: Okay I finally got it. I combined all other columns (except _id) to single column and finally applied .agg(collect_list()) on it. Thanks for your help.